# Usage Issue of std::align

Tags: c++, c++11, std, memory-alignment

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

// Visual Studio 2012 don't have alignof as a keyword.
#define alignof(type) __alignof(type) 

#define TEST_TYPE int

int main(int, char*[])
{
    TEST_TYPE i;
    void* pv = &i;
    size_t space = 100; // Just some big number.

    size_t alignment = alignof(TEST_TYPE);

    cout << "Alignment of int: " << alignment << endl;
    cout << "Is 'i' aligned: " 
         << (size_t(&i) % alignment == 0 ? "true" : "false" )
         << endl;

    if ( align(alignment, sizeof(TEST_TYPE), pv, space) )
    {
        TEST_TYPE* p = reinterpret_cast<TEST_TYPE*>(pv);

        cout << "Moved pointer " 
             << (size_t(p) - size_t(&i)) 
             << " bytes" 
             << endl;

        cout << "Is 'p' aligned: " 
             << (size_t(p) % alignment == 0 ? "true" : "false" )
             << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can't align 'i'" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It creates an (properly aligned) integer and then calls std::align with the address of the integer. The output I get is:

Alignment of int: 4 
Is 'i' aligned: true 
Moved pointer 4 bytes 
Is 'p' aligned: true

indicating that the pointer is moved, even though the address is already properly aligned. However, the documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) says it *"... modifies the ptr to point to the first possible address of such aligned storage..."* but wouldn't that mean the pointer should be unchanged?

So my question: Will the third argument to std::align (the pointer) always be changed to be one *size* greater if the argument pointer already is aligned?

**EDIT**

Also, if the pointer is NOT changed then will not the example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/align/?kw=align enter an infinite loop?

**2nd EDIT**

NOTE The link has been updated and the possible problem no longer occurs.

Comment: The output from clang++/libc++ is `Moved pointer 0 bytes`

Comment: If I change the pv pointer to &i - 1 byte (doing some uggly casting) the pointer will be moved 11 bytes.

Can this be a compiler bug?

Comment: (meant 5 bytes, had a different type in the macro.)

Comment: What compiler are you using, mine does not have `std::align` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in your standard library implementation, the output should be "Moved pointer 0 bytes" as `pv` is already aligned, so the first correctly aligned address in the range `[pv,pv+100)`, is `pv` itself, not `pv+4`.

Although it does say in the standard:

> The function updates its ptr and space arguments so that it can be called repeatedly with
>   possibly different alignment and size arguments for the same buffer

I'm not sure exactley what this is saying, or if it is relevant.  I don't think it is.

Comment: Looking at the implementation in VS11, it does look incorrect. How about the example on the second link? If align can leave the pointer alone if it's already aligned, isn't the loop missing an incrementation of the pointer?

Comment: @JensÅkerblom: Which link sorry?